# Center values in barplot

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I am trying to create a barplot, and I am almost happy with my result. What I have looks like this

[image]

The change I want can be seen in the image below. I am trying to center the values of each bar in the center of the bar. Also I do not want the 1 at the top, instead it should display the actual height of the red bar.

[image]

Any idea how to make these changes? I tried to look here http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/stacked-bar-plot/, but I am not sure what I am doing differently.

Also is there a way to avoid writing in the red bars? As I always want the blue one minus the red one to equal 1 in height.

## Code

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=20pt,
    x=1cm,
    nodes near coords,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ymin = 0,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Winning probability},
    symbolic x coords={tool1, tool2, tool3, tool4, 
        tool5, tool6, tool7, tool8},
    xtick={tool1, tool2, tool3, tool4, 
        tool5, tool6, tool7, tool8},
    xticklabels = {(1,8), (2,7), (3,6), (4,5), (5,4), (6,3), (7,2), (8,1)},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    ]
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {
    (tool1,0.778) 
    (tool2,0.611) 
    (tool3,0.500) 
    (tool4,0.444) 
    (tool5,0.444) 
    (tool6,0.500) 
    (tool7,0.611) 
    (tool8,0.778)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {
    (tool1,0.222) 
    (tool2,0.389) 
    (tool3,0.500) 
    (tool4,0.556) 
    (tool5,0.556) 
    (tool6,0.500) 
    (tool7,0.389) 
    (tool8,0.222)};
\legend{\strut Knut wins, \strut Nora wins}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
```

(or some higher version number) to the preamble.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Do you know how to change the color of the nodes? `\addplot+[ybar, red]` hides the textnodes completely. I know I can change the fill opacity, but if possible I would like to keep the strong colors and instead make the text lighter.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar `node near coords style={blue}`